# Creating Custom log levels in Logback logging framework

Tags: java

Can I add custom log levels like fine,finer and finest to the existing supported logback log levels. Apart from the existing ones I need to include additional log Levels.This addition should not effect the underlying code.

Thanks in advance...Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Logback is an implementation of Slf4J and in Slf4J levels are defined as enum (see [documentation](https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/event/Level.html)), so it does not seem to be possible.

However, you could conceivably use level TRACE and use [MDC](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html) to define custom sublevels. Then if you wanted to skip certain sublevel in logs, you could specify a [filter](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html) to disable them (either one of the EvaluatorFilters or a custom one).

Comment: I don't thick so MDC will resolve my issue.But wl try that and thanks for the info.

Answer (score -1):

I don’t know if this will help you but you can write logs with the java.io an nio package by writing what you want in a file using a filewriter

```
File f=new File("name");
BufferedWriter writer=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
```

Comment: How would this help? The OP wants to add custom levels to Logback, not write his own logging framework.